# Qt - Draw on canvas

Tags: qt, drawing, qt5

I am trying to write a program using `Qt5` that allows users to draw on canvas like paint. 
I know that the program has to handle events such as `mousePressEvent()`, `mouseReleaseEvent()`, and `mouseMoveEvent()`. But I am not able to figure out how to use them.

Can you guys give me a simple example on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have provided an example that shows this. https://bitbucket.org/jsuppe/qt-paint

What this example shows is:

- Create a widget & handle mouse events & paint event
- The widget contains a QImage which is the size of the widget.
- Write to the QImage the pixel coordinates when the mouse events occur
- Tell the widget to re-paint when pixels are changed on the QImage
- In the paintEvent I paint my QImage

I hope this helps

Update: I've since changed this sample to using QPainterPath to draw to the QImage. The old method is still there drawing pixels directly, but out of the box there is a lot more function with QPainterPath. I've also added a QML demo here: https://bitbucket.org/jsuppe/qt-paint-2

Comment: great app! let me know whenever you have any improvement on your work, thanks

Comment: I check the code but the image format "Format_RGBA8888" does not exist, it should be replace by "Format_RGB888". Thanks for this app.

Comment: @HugoBevilacqua, thanks I just made a few other updates as well if interested

Comment: Can we do this using only QML without using QWidgets ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy, I've created a new repo that is a minimal QML example here: https://bitbucket.org/jsuppe/qt-paint-2